# Деструктуризация обьекта в useSelector хранит все данные этого обькта? Как правильно использовать деструктуризацию с useSelector

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-hook

столкнулся с такой проблемой - решил оптимизировать React приложение и выяснил, что когда я деструктурирую два значения из обьекта, `const { quoteCurr, baseCurr } = useAppSelector(state => state.portfolio.selectedCoins)`, остальные значение обьекта при изменении в других компонентах заставляют этот компонент ре-рендериться.

Подскажите пожалуйста, что делать в такой ситуации? Не использовать деструктуризацию и создавать каждую переменную отдельно?
Вот так: `const baseCurr = useAppSelector(state => state.portfolio.selectedCoins.baseCurr); const quoteCurr = useAppSelector(state => state.portfolio.selectedCoins.quoteCurr);`

Вот что хранится в компоненте при деструктуризации, мне нужны только два значения обьекта, но компонент следит за именением 4

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Селектору не знает как ты используешь его результат. Если результат селектора меняется, то будет ререндер. 
Собственно смысл селектора ровно в том что бы ты выбирал только  нужные данные

Comment: @AlexeyTen Получается если я использую useSelector, то получаю весь обьект вне зависимости от того использую я где-то в коде компонента эту переменную или нет, ре-рендер при ее изменении все равно произойдет?

Comment: Ты получаешь ровно то что возвращает твоя функция. Селектор не знает и знать не может что из этого ты используешь. Ещё раз: собственно твоя задача как программиста возвращать там минимально необходимое количество данных что бы минимизировать ререндеры

Comment: @AlexeyTen Спасибо большое за ответ!)

Answer (score 0):

При изменении состояния будут вызваны все селекторы, что ты используешь.
Рендер произойдёт в том случае, если селектор возвратит значение, отличное от предыдущего. В том числе если сделать вот так:

```
const { count } = useSelector(state => ({ count: state.count }))
```

В данном случае компонент будет рендериться от любого изменения состояния, так как селектор всегда возвращает новый объект.